# Can you use RBAC to set individual permissions for each group?

Tags: php, yii, permissions, yii2, rbac

I have been investigating the best method to create a complex permission based system and I am using the `Yii2` framework and noticed it includes good `RBAC` support, however I am not sure if it is right for my situation.

What I am looking for I guess is similar to what a forum system would use where you can make groups and then you can select what permissions each of those groups are allowed to do.

I have noticed that with `RBAC` that you add your `roles` and if you add and `admin` and a `author` for example you can then add the `author` as a `child` of `admin` and then `admin` can do everything authors can + whatever other permissions you give them.

Do you have to do it like this or can you do all the permissions separately? Is adding the `author` as a `child` of `admin` just a quicker/cleaner way to give `admin` all the same permissions a lower level group has and then you can then add extra permissions on top?

I worry about doing it this way though because what if you remove a permission from the `author`, then all of a sudden the `admin` will lose that permission to unless they gain it from another child or are given it separately.

Can I still utilise `RBAC` for my needs or should I look at doing something custom?

Answer (score 0):

The RBAC system of Yii2 is very powerful,  you can effectly add yor group pemission to a parent and later if need to revoke a single permission the the child group you can  add what you need only when and how you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't really answer all my questions. As I pointed out I was concerned about the *inheritance* of permissions where an *admin* would *inherit* permissions from it's child groups; what happens if a permission it inherited from one of it's child groups gets revoked on the child - the *admin* group would lose that permission as well? I guess because of this issue I was asking if you could just avoid adding children and set *all* the permissions for *each* group separately?

Comment: When you revoke a permission to the chiild obviously this is lost and you can add this permission  to the parent separately

Comment: Seems like a bit of a pain to manage if you had to do it that way. Would you know if I can do it separately as specified in my last question - you don't *have* to add them as children right?

Comment: I use both strategy in some case i use a superAdmin with proper permissione, an admin with admin permission and several group of operational application permission. This with different level of deep in function of the application permission needs.

Comment: When I need to change the hierarchy or I need to reorganize the permits in general or those specifically assigned to groups, I look for any work where it is most appropriate to intervene, if at group level or unbundle permits and redistribute them on time or in the form subgroup.It happens to manage even very complex structures permits, detailed and have never encountered any problems. I do not know if this can help, or details in more depth your needs with a real example.

Comment: Thanks for that; although I didn't quite understand a lot of it. Perhaps because of the language barrier.